# Is there any way to add values from 2 matrices together in order to get a 'grand total'?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have created a report in SSRS that contains 2 matrices (not tables/lists), each with a subtotal. What I am trying to work out is if there is any way to calculate a 'grand total' at the bottom of my report that is the sum of the subtotals from my 2 matrices.

Matrix 1:
       10
       10
       10
       5
       10
       5
       5
 Total 55

Matrix 2:
       20
       10
       10
       5
       20
       5
       5
 Total 75

Grand Total: 130

Each matrix is driven from a separate datasource btw.

Essentially what I am trying to end up with is

> =sum(fields!gross.Value,"matrix1")+sum(fields!gross.Value,"matrix2")

as grand total, but this doesn't work.

As I said, I'm new to this so the above syntax may be incorrect, though I hope it gives you an idea of what I am trying to achieve.

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using "matrix1" and "matrix2" use the name of the dataset for each one.

```
 =sum(fields!gross.Value,"Dataset1") + sum(fields!gross.Value,"Dataset2")
```

Also, sometimes if your data types are not explicit, you will have to cast your fields like so:

```
 sum(CDec(fields!gross.Value),"Dataset1")
```

But you will probably not have to do that in this case.